# DynamoDb: Arguments for delete_item

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a FastAPI method for delete_item in DynamoDb

```
@app.delete("/delete-student/{student_id}")
def delete_student(student_id : str):
    db = connect_ddb()
    try:
        response = db.delete_item(Key={"id": student_id})
        return response
    except Exception as error:
        return {"error message": error}
```

And I'm testing using the requests library

```
x = requests.delete('endpoint/prod/delete-student/7')
>>> 
'{"error":"student_id: {student_id} does not exist"}'
```

I've successfully posted student id=7 and retrieved student id=7. So I'm confused what's wrong with the delete-student method. {"error message": ...} is not returned, but rather {"error":...} This means that the try clause worked and the response is from DynamoDb (not the except clause.)

So my question is, what issue does Ddb have with the argument, student_id?

Is Key={"id": student_id} wrong for delete_item? Note, this is the same argument for get_item, which does return the associated student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show your code that's returning the response. DynamoDB does not return the message you posted.

`'{"error":"student_id: {student_id} does not exist"}`

If the item didn't exist, DynamoDB would simply return a 200 success.

The parameters expected by a deleteItem are exactly the same as a getItem which is the full primary key.

Comment: I'm sorry, `response = db.delete_item(Key={"id": student_id}) \ return response` is listed just below try. Could you clarify what you're referring to?

Comment: The exception message you post, it does not originate from DynamoDB. So it's not the response you get back, it's originating elsewhere.